# Can't add public IP to allowed connections for GCloud SQL instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add an allowed public IP address following CIDR notation to the allowed networks on my GCloud SQL instance, however when I click "Save", it just sits there saying "Saving" but doesn't actually do anything. I've left it for various periods of time, the longest being half an hour, yet it has made no difference, the changes are still not saved.

Any ideas?

Edit: I've now fixed the initial issue by disabling Private IP access, however now I get "Operation failed: This operation isn"t valid for this instance." every time I try and save the Public IP settings. I'd ask Google for help but I don't fancy paying them $150 for them to fix their own system...

Comment: Are all the API needed for private ip address activated?

Comment: @night-gold I don't know, I gave up and moved to Azure, which has much better security features and a much easier firewall

Comment: Close the question if you don't need an answer :)